# models.User.fromURI fails

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

When invoking models.User.fromURI like this

```
models.User.fromURI("spotify:user:" + user, function (user) {
            $(div).html("<b ><a style=\"color:#FFFFFF\" href=\"spotify:user:" + user.username + "\">" + user + "</a></b><br />" + text + "");
        });
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getUserByUsername'
```

Answer (score 0):

User is not a public class for developers. It's only used internally. Please use only documented API calls found on the developer website.

Comment: if you're talking about the user class, I have no indication that we will open it up anytime soon.

Comment: The reason for it is privacy I read somewhere. But I feel we need a more accurate working API, more brief controls and views (like pager, popovers etc.). Such views exists with some hacking and it seems the major apps has some "ultra" permissions to controls and features we outstanders can't understand. Is there some special priviligues to the top brands?